# Terminal errors on terminal startup

Tags: command-line, bash, find

Whenever I start the Terminal, I get two errors at the top that say `-bash: export:`, then a path string, and then `: not a valid identifier`.  I know that these errors are being thrown because of an equal sign (`=`) in the path for some reason.  My question is: what file is running these `export` commands?  Is there any way to see what files are running when the terminal starts?

**By the way:** the path string in the error is old, it is one I used to have before it was changed.  I updated the `/etc/environment/` file to what it is now, so I think I may have ran something that changed a startup file, and then when I uninstalled it, it left the export.

Comment: Look into `~/.profile` or `~/bash_profile`, perhaps it's set there

Comment: Have a look a the following files: `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`

Comment: I checked all of those, and nothing related to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the problem might just be in the modified `/etc/environment` file; since you said you modified this, why didn't you post the contents?

Most likely, it is something fairly simple, like a space or spaces around the equals sign.  If you put something like `export foo = bar` instead of `export foo=bar`, then the shell will attempt to export 3 variables:  "foo", "=", and "bar".

Why are you modifying that file?  Normally, you should modify `$HOME/.bash_profile` unless you have multiple users who need the same path.  If you are administering a system for multiple users, then you need to be more careful in making changes.

Also, you should be more careful about posting quoted error messages; you misspelled "identifier".  It's better to actually cut and paste errors to get them exact.

Comment: Sorry, i was doing this on my phone so i couldn't copy+paste.  Thanks for the catch though.

Comment: I see.  Thanks for the explanation, and glad it helped.